# What to do when there is heteroskedasticity in an ANCOVA model?

Tags: r, regression, anova, heteroscedasticity, ancova

What to do when there is heteroskedasticity in an ANCOVA model?
Is there a correction similar to Welch ANOVA?
Or is better to use a OLS regression model?
Should we try to solve heteroskedasticity by using transformations on the response or the covariates?

In R, the function

```
oneway.test()
```

does not work when there is a continuous predictor.